# Osmosis Error. Converting osm data to msql database

Tags: java, mysql, parsing, routes, openstreetmap

I want to get the osm data and put it in a mysql database but the error indicated below is raised by osmosis.

I need the data of an osm file to convert int to matrix then put a depot area  and treat user's selected nodes as nodes like graph and i will get the fastest o efficient path to route a vehicle with capacity to get some things in the nodes and if the vehicle is full then it will return to the starting area and unload it's current loads then go back to the remaining nodes to get their loads.

```
20-Nov-2011 15:42:45 org.openstreetmap.osmosis.core.pipeline.common.ActiveTaskMa
nager waitForCompletion
SEVERE: Thread for task 2-buffer failed
org.openstreetmap.osmosis.core.OsmosisRuntimeException: Unable to bulk insert re
lation members into the database.
        at org.openstreetmap.osmosis.apidb.v0_6.ApidbWriter.flushRelationMembers
(ApidbWriter.java:895)
        at org.openstreetmap.osmosis.apidb.v0_6.ApidbWriter.addRelationMembers(A
pidbWriter.java:1229)
        at org.openstreetmap.osmosis.apidb.v0_6.ApidbWriter.flushRelations(Apidb
Writer.java:829)
        at org.openstreetmap.osmosis.apidb.v0_6.ApidbWriter.complete(ApidbWriter
.java:1044)
        at org.openstreetmap.osmosis.core.buffer.v0_6.EntityBuffer.run(EntityBuf
fer.java:77)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Incorrect integer value: 'Way' for column 'mem
ber_type' at row 1
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1055)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:956)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3558)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3490)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:1959)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2109)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2648)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.ja
va:2077)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java
:2362)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java
:2280)
        at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java
:2265)
        at org.openstreetmap.osmosis.apidb.v0_6.ApidbWriter.flushRelationMembers
(ApidbWriter.java:893)
        ... 5 more
20-Nov-2011 15:42:45 org.openstreetmap.osmosis.core.Osmosis main
SEVERE: Execution aborted.
org.openstreetmap.osmosis.core.OsmosisRuntimeException: One or more tasks failed
.
        at org.openstreetmap.osmosis.core.pipeline.common.Pipeline.waitForComple
tion(Pipeline.java:146)
        at org.openstreetmap.osmosis.core.Osmosis.run(Osmosis.java:92)
        at org.openstreetmap.osmosis.core.Osmosis.main(Osmosis.java:37)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchStandard(Laun
cher.java:329)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.jav
a:239)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(La
uncher.java:409)
        at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:
352)
        at org.codehaus.classworlds.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:31)
C:\Users\home\Desktop>
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, the stacktrace is quite obvious:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Incorrect integer value:
  'Way' for column 'member_type' at row 1
```

You are trying to pass a string "Way" to the integer-column "member_type".